# Using a custom socket recvall function works only, if thread is put to sleep

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following socket listening on my local network:

```
def recvall(sock):
    BUFF_SIZE = 4096 # 4 KiB
    fragments = []
    while True: 
        chunk = sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
        fragments.append(chunk)
        # if the following line is removed, data is omitted
        time.sleep(0.005)
        if len(chunk) < BUFF_SIZE: 
            break
        
    data = b''.join(fragments)
    return data

def main():

    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(('192.168.0.22', 2525))
    print("starting listening...")
    s.listen(1)
    counter = 0
    while True:
        clientsocket, address = s.accept()
        print(f"Connection from {address} has been established!")
        received_data = recvall(clientsocket)
        clientsocket.send(bytes(f"response nr {counter}!", "utf-8"))
        counter += 1
        print(len(received_data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To this port, I'm sending byte data with a length of `172800` bytes from an app on my mobile phone.
As one can see, I'm printing the amount of data received. The amount is only correct, if I use `time.sleep()` as shown in the code above. If I don't use this method, only a part of the data is received.

Obviously this is some timing issue, the question is: How can I be sure to receive all the data all the time without using `time.sleep()` (since this is also not 100% certain to work, depending on the sleeping time set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sock.recv()` returns the data that is available. The relevant piece from the man page of [`recv(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/recv.2.en.html) is:

```
The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount,
rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.
```

In your case, `time.sleep(0.005)` seems to allow for all the remaining data of the message to arrive and be stored in the buffer.

There are some options to eliminate the need for `time.sleep(0.005)`. Which one is the most appropriate depends on your needs.

1. If the sender sends data, but does not expect a response, you can have the sender close the socket after it sends the data, i.e., `sock.close()` after `sock.sendall()`. `recv()` will return an empty string that can be used to break out of the `while` loop on the receiver.

```py
def recvall(sock):
    BUFF_SIZE = 4096
    fragments = []
    while True: 
        chunk = sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
        if not chunk:
            break
        fragments.append(chunk)
    return b''.join(fragments)
```

2. If the sender sends messages of fixed length, e.g., `172800` bytes, you can use `recv()` in a loop until the receiver receives an entire message.

```py
def recvall(sock, length=172800):
    fragments = []
    while length:
        chunk = sock.recv(length)
        if not chunk:
            raise EOFError('socket closed')
        length -= len(chunk)
        fragments.append(chunk)
    return b''.join(fragments)
```

3. Other options include a. adding a delimiter, e.g., a special character that cannot be part of the data, at the end of the messages that the sender sends; the receiver can then run `recv()` in a loop until it detects the delimiter and b. prefixing the messages on the sender with their length; the receiver will then know how many bytes to expect for each message.